# Adding an img inline with the content only on a specific page

Tags: theming

I have a certain page on my site that has the following menus at the top:

[image]

I would like to add a logo just before the textual menus on the far left of the screen.  This menu is in the main content of the page.  So far I have been able to get the logo to show up just above the content by adding the img to my page.tpl.php file but I really want it to show up on the same line as my menus.

I thought maybe I could do this by adding the img into a region.tpl.php file but that would make the image show up on every page's region and I only want it to show up on this page's region.  Is there a way to the image show up inline using a page.tpl.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a block with your context, restricting the block to that one page, and then assigning the block to the correct region?

Your regions will depend on your theme.

Comment: Is it possible to put a menu inside a block?

Comment: All menus are available as blocks, if more functionality needed, try the menu_block module